# What is $x$ in a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, binomial-coefficients

I know this sounds like an easy question. But I've never been told this.

Suppose we have a polynomial...

$$3x^2 + 5x - 9$$

I know $3$, $5$ and $-9$ are *coefficients*.

I also know $2$ (form $3x^2$), $1$ (from $5x$) and $0$ (from $-9$) are *exponents*.

But what is the term for $x$?

I'm trying to refer to it in a report.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)

Comment: It's a variable.

Comment: @LanierFreeman If I'd use the term variable, I'd probably say "*the* variable of the polynomial"

Comment: Unless you are dealing with pure math, you need to consider the problem domain. For example, in Physics, the equation you gave may represent distance, speed or time in a particular experiment.

Comment: @NoChance Note that there is difference between the algebraic object "polynomial" and the analytic object "polynomial function" - the latter one always has a domain, especially in pure math.

Comment: @Roland, that is something new to me. I did not know the difference before. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is:

- If we're dealing with formal polynomials, then $x$ is called an *indeterminate.*
- If we're dealing with polynomial functions, then $x$ is called a *variable.*

You may also find the following terminology useful: a polynomial in one indeterminate is said to be *univariate,* a polynomial in two indeterminates is said to be *bivariate*, etc. Unfortunately, these kinds of things are a little ambiguous, given current notational conventions. For example, $x^2+1$ would usually be considered unvariate; however, we may be thinking of it as living in the ring of polynomials in the indeterminates $\{x,y\},$ in which case we're thinking of it as bivariate. To make matters even worse, a polynomial like $y^3x^2+(y^2+1)x+1$ is sometimes thought of as a **univariate** polynomial in the indeterminates $\{x\}$ with coefficients in the ring of polynomials in the indeterminates $\{y\}$! Those poor students...

Comment: Thank you so much. I tend to understand the Maths, but lose focus on the terminology.

Comment: @MaxEchendu, I'd say that's pretty normal!